# How to change the value of variable in called target in ant

Tags: ant

can i change the value of parameter in called target and then retrieve it in the calling target in ant.Probably By refid if there is any other way that is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a property in ANT as mutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789756/how-to-make-a-property-in-ant-as-mutable)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you cannot modify an ant property in ant once it's set, but as oers pointed out in a comment, you can use the [Variable](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) task in ant-contrib.  You can even override an existing property with a Variable. According to the documentation, you should still use properties in most cases, and only use variables in the cases where you really need to be able to modify a value.

Another workaround is to set additional properties and call the other targets using those properties.

Comment: [you can with ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html).